# Show UltraMessageBox in the same screen during multi monitor scenario

Tags: infragistics

I am trying to display a UltraMessageBox and it works fine when I use a single monitor, but If I open my application to second monitor, the message box is hiding behind other opened applications in the 1st monitor.

Is there any setting I can set the UltraMessageBoxManager so that the opened message box shows in the same monitor as the application?

Answer (score 0):

There are two essential properties in [UltraMessageBoxInfo](https://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/infragistics.win~infragistics.win.ultramessagebox.ultramessageboxinfo) class that allows you to position the message box wherever you want, if there is even more than one monitor.

**StartLocation**

> Specify the start-up location of the message box. This
>   value is taken under consideration only when StartPosition property is
>   set to Manual.

**StartPosition**

> Specify the initial position of the dialog. If the enumeration is set
>   to Manual, then the location of the form is determined by the
>   StartLocation property.

More information about how to setup **StartPosition** and **StartLocation** with code snippet is available at https://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/winmessageboxmanager-setting-up-the-startposition-and-startlocation-properties

Comment: I can't find this property in UltraMessageBoxInfo in version14.2, is there any alternative available for this version?

Comment: Which version you use?

Comment: I am using 2014.2 version

Comment: These properties were introduced in 15.2. More information at https://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/whats-new-in-2015-volume-2

Comment: We are not considering the upgrade option currently for our application, is there any workaround available for version 14.2?